# Input Radio Groups Matching on Different Tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net, radio-button

I have two set of `<input type="radio" />` button groups that are on the same html page but in different `<td>`s. When the user chooses one from either set I want the other set to have the one selected and give the same value.

Example: If the user selected 1 on group with the name `VT2`, and then the user changes(Autopostback) to the other table that `<input type="radio" />` button group with name `VT22` will have the same `<input type="radio" />` button checked and giving the same value.

```html
<td>
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT2" value="1" checked />1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT2" value="1"/>2</label>&nbsp;
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT2" value="1"/>3</label>&nbsp;
</td>
<td>
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT22" value="1" checked />1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT22" value="1"/>2</label>&nbsp;
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT22" value="1"/>3</label>&nbsp;
</td>
```

This is what I have for JavaScript but I have tried many things and cannot figure out what to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var vt2 = document.getElementsByName("VT2");
    var vt22 = document.getElementsByName("VT22");

    for (i = 0; i < vt2.length; i++) {
        if (vt2.length > 0){

        } else if (vt22.length > 0){

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want? (i'm using jquery 2.2)
https://jsfiddle.net/twLfasky/

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT2" value="1" checked />1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT2" value="2"/>2</label>&nbsp;
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT2" value="3"/>3</label>&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT22" value="1" />1</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT22" value="2"/>2</label>&nbsp;
  <label><input type="radio" name="VT22" value="3"/>3</label>&nbsp;
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('[name="VT2"]').change(function() {
  var secondRadioGroup = $('[name="VT22"]');
  var checkedValue = $('[name="VT2"]:checked').val();

  for(var i=0; i<= secondRadioGroup.length -1; i++) {

    if( checkedValue === secondRadioGroup[i].value ) {

        secondRadioGroup[i].setAttribute('checked', true);
      secondRadioGroup[i].setAttribute('value', checkedValue);

    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Will this work for both sets of input radio button groups? if they are on one table and go back and forth it will be the same?

Comment: i find a bug on my script, i'm updating it now